# Running multiple pytest files one after the other

Tags: python

I need to run several pytest files in one script file

I used subprocess.Popen used in pytest and unittest.

In both cases I did not get the desired results.

I tried the following ways:

```
//all_tests_files - an array with all tests folders
for file in all_tests_files:
    # get path of the test
    f = os.listdir(PATH + '\\' + file)
    for test in f:
        x1 = test.find('test_')
        x2 = test.find('.py')
        if x1 is 0 and x2 is not -1:
            p = PATH + '\\' + file + '\\' + test
            print("--- RUN TEST: " + test + " ---")
            test_process = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-m', 'unittest', p])
            test_process.wait()
```

In this way using unittest I receive the result of the tests but not in the right order, first the final result and then the prints that are in the tests themselves.

```
            test_process = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-m', 'pytest', p])
            test_process.wait()
```

in the second way using pytest I only receive the final result and not the prints of each test.

How can I get full results in the right order?

Comment: Your code sems to be correct. Please edit your question: copy-paste the outputs (full, no omitting), explain where they are wrong, and write the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

`pytest` allows multiple test modules per invocation, like

```
python -m pytest tests/test_foo.py tests/test_bar.py
```

I'd just do

```
test_files = []
for test_folder in all_tests_files:
    test_files.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(PATH, test_folder, "test_*.py"))
print(test_files)  # for debugging
proc = subprocess.Popen([
    sys.interpreter,
    '-m',
    'pytest',
    *test_files,
])
proc.wait()
```

Comment: I tried this way and I still didn't get the all results

Comment: It's hard to tell what "the all results" you're looking for are. Use `-s` if you want Pytest to not capture standard output.